# Xcode unable to open proper class in Assistant Editor for class UICollectionReusableView

Tags: swift, xcode, editor, assistant

I have a Collection View scene with associated Cocoa class (working right), and this View contains two Generic Collection Reusable Views. I created Cocoa classes of UICollectionReusableView and set them here.

[image]

But when I start assistant editor, it is still opening class for whole view (of UICollectionView) , of course I selected my Generic collection reusable view.

Even when the other class is set properly. I don't have a choice. Here is a picture.

[image]

I am unable to open my GenericCollectionReusableView.swift with assistant editor.

Please any suggestions?

After the moment when it was working for me, I added a new Table View Controller, and created a class for a cell. And again same problem, Option-click or other ways not working, even the assistant editor lets me choose proper file, but unable to drop over there, see on the image. I don't understand how to use it. There are no questions about it, so I must do something badly, but it seems so easy.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try some ways below:

1. Click onto right side, Shift+Command+O, paste the class name you
   expect to open. Ex: GenericCollectionReusableView
2. As image below, you can click onto anywhere in red rectangle, this will show popup for you direct to your expected file.
   [image]

Comment: Thanks so much, this sounds very logic, maybe I am doing something wrong. After I find my file in quick open and press enter, it will open new file but not on storyboard or assistant, if I not press the enter and click into red rectangle zone, still I have just 2 options, header file or class I don't want. Should I do something after opening quick open, please?

Comment: @Mlok quick tips, Option + click on the file in Project navigator that you wanna to open assistant editor

Comment: it will open a file in new separate section not in assistant editor :( So I am unable to control drag over here :( I am doing something wrong, I am not good on using clickable interfaces :)

Comment: I got it, Option click on reverse :) first I have to open swift file, than option click on Storyboard! Many thanks to You!

Comment: I am missing some kind of understanding. I have another same situation Option click does not work (not open in assistant editor, just two windows unable to Control-drag), trying everything without success, it is in UITableView with custom cell class.

Comment: Update: Now I can choose from popup in red border proper class, but I am unable to drop Ctrl-drag here :( I can see the line after mouse, but unable to drop it. I am without idea how to work with it.

Comment: @Mlok When you click the red rectangle it'll have 2 files: 1 is the file you expected and 1 file is Interface (which file have text Interface text in bracket after the file name - this file cannot drop outlet) . Just click the icon in left side (icon have 4 square), reselect the correct file you expected and you can ctrl+drag to this file

Comment: Thanks, I will try next time, I "fixed" it deleting view controller and configuring every piece before I make any changes to settings in inspector view. That worked ... But when I make some change, it stops to work.

Comment: @thenakulchawla long time ago, I don't use Control Drag =)). If needed, I write all IBOutlet code in swift file, after that I move to Storyboard, drag each outlet for each UI. With me this will be easier and will not meet the problem as like this topic ^_^